# Fill progress bars based on items in list

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have three lists `A`, `B` and `C`.

Lists `A` and `C` contain li items that get filled into list `B` via clicks. This is how it currently looks like:

https://jsfiddle.net/3ds06kf0/92/

Now I want to use two HTML5  bars to indicate the status of the "filled" list `B`.

The first bar that fills from left to right stands for "items filled" from list `A`, the second bar that fills from right to left stands for "items filled" from list `C`.

Every time an item from one of the lists gets moved to list `B`, the respective progress bar should fill up by a set amount, let's say 10%. If the max of one the progress bars (currently set to 100) is reached, it should no longer be possible to fill an item into list `B` from the full progress bar's list.

It'd be great if that would work backwards as well, so whenever you remove an item from list `B`, the value should be substracted from the respective progress bar.

Does anyone have a clue how to approach this? Thanks in advance for the help!

PS: I have set the current value of both progress bars to 10% to show the colors and directions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this works. I set a configurable step of 25 to be able to reach the max with your example:

```js
var step = 25;
var current = {
  'listA': parseInt($('.listAprogress').val()),
  'listC': parseInt($('.listCprogress').val())
};
var maxValues = {
  'listA': parseInt($('.listAprogress').attr('max')),
  'listC': parseInt($('.listCprogress').attr('max'))
};

$("#listA,#listC").on('click', 'li', function() {
  if (current['listA'] >= maxValues['listA'] || current['listC'] >= maxValues['listC']) {
    alert("max reached");
    return;
  }
  var prev_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  var prev_index = $(this).index();

  $(this).attr('prev_id', prev_id);
  $(this).attr('prev_index', prev_index);

  var thisli = $(this).clone();
  $('#listB').append(thisli);
  $(this).hide();
  updateProgress(prev_id, step);
});

$('#listB').on('click', 'li', function() {
  var prev_id = $(this).attr('prev_id');
  var prev_index = $(this).attr('prev_index');

  $('#' + prev_id).children().eq(prev_index).show();
  $(this).remove();
  updateProgress(prev_id, -step);
});

function updateProgress(listId, step) {
  current[listId] += step;
  $('.' + listId + 'progress').val(current[listId]);
}
```

```css
#listA,
#listB,
#listC {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 2.5em;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.listAprogress,
.listCprogress {
  /* Reset the default appearance */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
}

.listCprogress {
  direction: rtl;
}

.listCprogress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: red;
}

ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #666;
}

ul li:hover {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><progress class="listAprogress" max="100" value="0"></progress></div>

<div><progress class="listCprogress" max="100" value="0"></progress></div>

<ul id="listA">List A
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="listB">List B
</ul>

<ul id="listC" class="connectedSortable">List C
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 7</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 8</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 9</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Jesus Christ, you're a beast! Thank you SO much!

Comment: @tharid you're welcome! :)

Comment: One more question: Do you think it's possible to set different values for different items in that code as well?

Comment: @tharid Yes, add an attribute to the `<li>` elements, read it from the click handler events and use that value instead of `step`

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, I tried to insert different values, but I can't seem to get quite through it ... Would I need to run different scripts for different values? Because `step` is the set value in all the functions, so I can't any an arbitray amount of other values?

Comment: @tharid That's why I said you need to use attribute value **instead of** `step`. You should remove `step` variable.

Comment: @tharid See working example: https://jsfiddle.net/cCrul/v9dm4qx8/

Comment: Hello @raul.vila, I tried to implement this, but the progress bar only works one way with your example regarding different value. Could you look over your example one more time? That'd be great!

Comment: @tharid sorry, I don't understand your problem. I suggest you post a new question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm refering to your working example from April 20th where you added customStep to read different values: https://jsfiddle.net/cCrul/v9dm4qx8/

I tried it out, and it fills the bars with different values, but when I move items back to their old lists, the progress bar keeps being filled up, but it should remove the progress when I remove the item from the middle list!

Comment: @tharid Oh, I see. It's fixed here: https://jsfiddle.net/v9dm4qx8/2

Comment: Thanks a ton, Raul!