# Update progress bar scalability

Tags: jquery, html

a couple weeks ago I had a problem where I wanted to fill two progress bars based on the values of two lists who sort their list items into a third list. This was the great result:

[Fill progress bars based on items in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49939725/fill-progress-bars-based-on-items-in-list)

This is the JSFiddle for the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/3b69frvy/

Now I want to clone the three lists, the two progress bars  and their functionality to get displayed in another div. I tried to rename everything accordingly, but after I do that the progress bars don't fill up anymore, which can be seen in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/es3wsxet/

```
Code see JSFiddle
```

Can someone help me to clone the progress bar functionality? The optimal result would be two of these constructs next to each other :)

Comment: I did as the first answer suggested, but the progress bars still don't show anything:
 jsfiddle.net/es3wsxet/2

Comment: I found the reason why my example didn't work, it was because the progress bar class needs "progress" at the END of its name no matter what. I don't know why, but I don't care :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><progress class="listA_2progress" max="100" value="0"></progress></div>

<div><progress class="listC_2progress" max="100" value="0"></progress></div>

<ul id="listA_2" class="testtable">List A
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="listB_2" class="testtable">List B
</ul>

<ul id="listC_2" class="testtable">List C
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 7</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 8</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 9</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 10</li>
</ul>
```

And This JS

```
var step = 25;
var current = {
  'listA_2': parseInt($('.listA_2progress').val()),
  'listC_2': parseInt($('.listC_2progress').val())
};
var maxValues = {
  'listA_2': parseInt($('.listAprogress').attr('max')),
  'listC_2': parseInt($('.listCprogress').attr('max'))
};

$("#listA_2,#listC_2").on('click', 'li', function() {
  if (current['listA_2'] >= maxValues['listA_2'] || current['listC_2'] >= maxValues['listC_2']) {
    alert("max reached");
    return;
  }
  var prev_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  var prev_index = $(this).index();

  $(this).attr('prev_id', prev_id);
  $(this).attr('prev_index', prev_index);

  var thisli = $(this).clone();
  $('#listB_2').append(thisli);
  $(this).hide();
  updateProgress(prev_id, step);
});

$('#listB_2').on('click', 'li', function() {
  var prev_id = $(this).attr('prev_id');
  var prev_index = $(this).attr('prev_index');

  $('#' + prev_id).children().eq(prev_index).show();
  $(this).remove();
  updateProgress(prev_id, -step);
});

function updateProgress(listId, step) {
  current[listId] += step;
  $('.' + listId + 'progress').val(current[listId]);
}
```

You just forgot to rename the classname of the progress bar too

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for the answer! I did everything you did the way it is supposed to be named in my HTML, but the progress bar still doesn't react:
https://jsfiddle.net/es3wsxet/

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: I'm sorry, this is the JSFiddle I'm referring to in the answer above: https://jsfiddle.net/es3wsxet/2/

Comment: Thanks a lot, Razin!